# Why does my code not work when the given input exceeds 2 digits?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
romanD = {'I': 1, 'V': 5, 'X': 10, 'L': 50, 'C': 100, 'D': 500, 'M': 1000}
oper = []
s = input('roman')
i = 0


class Solution(object):
    def romanToInt(self, s):
        rtype = int
        # for i in range(len(s)-1):
        for j in range(1, len(s)):
            i = 0
            if i >= len(s):
                break
            elif romanD[s[i]] < romanD[s[j]]:
                oper.append(-1 * romanD[s[i]])
            elif romanD[s[i]] >= romanD[s[j]]:
                oper.append(romanD[s[i]])
            i += 1
        oper.append(romanD[s[len(s) - 1]])
        return sum(oper)


b = Solution()
print(b.romanToInt(s))
```

I go step by step with the runs:

L
returns 50

LV
returns 55

LVI
returns 101

I don't know where I'm going wrong. For some reason, at 3 digits, it adds the first value twice and ignores the second value.

Comment: Why do you have i and j?? Just have one.

Comment: I tried having one variable, as luk said, and it worked. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you uncomment `for i in range(len(s)-1):` out, you get 56 ;)

```
romanD = {'I': 1, 'V': 5, 'X': 10, 'L': 50, 'C': 100, 'D': 500, 'M': 1000}
oper = []
s = input('roman')
i = 0


class Solution(object):
    def romanToInt(self, s):
        rtype = int
        for i in range(len(s)-1):
            for j in range(1, len(s)):
                if i >= len(s):
                    break
                elif romanD[s[i]] < romanD[s[j]]:
                    oper.append(-1 * romanD[s[i]])
                elif romanD[s[i]] >= romanD[s[j]]:
                    oper.append(romanD[s[i]])
                i += 1
            oper.append(romanD[s[len(s) - 1]])
            return sum(oper)

b = Solution()
print(b.romanToInt(s))
```

You can check it out [here](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=romanD%20%3D%20%7B%27I%27%3A%201,%20%27V%27%3A%205,%20%27X%27%3A%2010,%20%27L%27%3A%2050,%20%27C%27%3A%20100,%20%27D%27%3A%20500,%20%27M%27%3A%201000%7D%0Aoper%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0As%20%3D%20input%28%27roman%27%29%0Ai%20%3D%200%0A%0A%0Aclass%20Solution%28object%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20def%20romanToInt%28self,%20s%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rtype%20%3D%20int%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20i%20in%20range%28len%28s%29-1%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20j%20in%20range%281,%20len%28s%29%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20i%20%3E%3D%20len%28s%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20break%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20elif%20romanD%5Bs%5Bi%5D%5D%20%3C%20romanD%5Bs%5Bj%5D%5D%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20oper.append%28-1%20*%20romanD%5Bs%5Bi%5D%5D%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20elif%20romanD%5Bs%5Bi%5D%5D%20%3E%3D%20romanD%5Bs%5Bj%5D%5D%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20oper.append%28romanD%5Bs%5Bi%5D%5D%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20i%20%2B%3D%201%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20oper.append%28romanD%5Bs%5Blen%28s%29%20-%201%5D%5D%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20sum%28oper%29%0A%0A%0Ab%20%3D%20Solution%28%29%0Aprint%28b.romanToInt%28s%29%29&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=edit&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%22LVI%22%5D&textReferences=false). Also shown in the pic:

[image]

Comment: and remove `i = 0` :)

Answer (score 2):

This happens because `i = 0` is in the `for j in range()` loop, so `i` will always be `0`. To fix this just put `i = 0` before the loop like this:

```
def romanToInt(self, s):
        rtype = int
        # for i in range(len(s)-1):
        i = 0  # <---- here :)
        for j in range(1, len(s)):
            if i >= len(s):
                break
            elif romanD[s[i]] < romanD[s[j]]:
                oper.append(-1 * romanD[s[i]])
            elif romanD[s[i]] >= romanD[s[j]]:
                oper.append(romanD[s[i]])
            i += 1
        oper.append(romanD[s[len(s) - 1]])
        return sum(oper)
```

Answer (score 0):

Magically, I still don't know how removing i fixed everything. But it did.

```
romanD = {'I': 1, 'V': 5, 'X': 10, 'L': 50, 'C': 100, 'D': 500, 'M': 1000}
oper = []
s = input('roman')


class Solution(object):
    def romanToInt(self, s):
        rtype = int
        for j in range(len(s)):
            if j+1 >= len(s):
                break
            elif romanD[s[j]] < romanD[s[j+1]]:
                oper.append(-1 * romanD[s[j]])
            elif romanD[s[j]] >= romanD[s[j+1]]:
                oper.append(romanD[s[j]])
        oper.append(romanD[s[len(s) - 1]])
        return sum(oper)


b = Solution()
print(b.romanToInt(s))
```